# How to find find all possible arguments to classes in bpy.types.*?

Tags: python

I know I can use something like `print(dir(bpy.types.FModifierLimits))` to find all possible "attributes". But what about arguments?

```
bpy.types.FModifierLimits(arg)
```

How would I print arg?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196960/can-you-list-the-keyword-arguments-a-python-function-receives have the techniques you need?

Comment: do you mean how do you find : https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FModifierLimits.html?highlight=bpy.types.fmodifierlimits#bpy.types.FModifierLimits through introspection from the REPL? (`max_x`,`max_y`.....,`use_min_y`)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly.

An existing instance is *always* passed into classes from `bpy.types`, however this is not common usage when creating new classes in the Blender Python API.

---

Blender/Python types aren't instantiated by calling the classes.

To create a new object for eg:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("name", None)
```

not:

```
obj = bpy.types.Object()
```

---

There is one use-case for calling a class, and that is to create a new instance of existing data *(however this is quite esoteric and not normally useful in practice)*.

This example creates an instance of a subclass of `bpy.types.Object`.

```
>>> class MyObjectSubclass(bpy.types.Object):
...     def my_helper_function():
...         print(42)
...
>>> obj_a = bpy.data.objects.new("name", None)
>>> obj_b = MyObjectSubclass(obj_a)
>>> obj_a is obj_b
False
>>> obj_a == obj_b
True
>>> obj_b.my_helper_function()
42
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want a way of figuring out what goes in the "()". some things require something in the "()".

Comment: Updated answer.